# How to enter country code in dropdown instead of scrolling the country code in dropdown in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new in angular and ionic framework, I would like to ask assistance in one of the requirements in our app. One of the requirements in our app is to input the user's phone number. The current implementation is the user will scroll the country code inside the dropdown to input phone number. We want to change the behavior for the convenience of the user. Instead of scrolling the country code, we would like to provide options that the user can input the country code and filter based on the inputted country code. Please see image below.

[image: sample image]

Here is current implementation in our app.

**.html**

```
<div class="phone_picker">
    <button type="button" (click)="openSelect()">{{ selectedCode }}</button>
    <div class="country_picker" *ngIf="toggleSelect">
      <div
        class="c_list ion-activatable ripple-parent"
        *ngFor="let c of countrycode"
        (click)="selectPhoneCode(c.dialcode)"
      >
        <div class="c_box">
          <img
            src="{{
              'assets'
            }}"
            alt="..."
          />
          <span>{{ c.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-input
      appIntegerInput
      type="tel"
      (keyup)="numberOnlyValidation($event)"
      onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
      [(ngModel)]="updateprofile.MobilePhone"
      [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
      class="phone_input"
      placeholder="Phone number"
      minlength="8"
      maxlength="12"
      inputmode="numeric"
      pattern="[0-9]*"
    ></ion-input>
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
   openSelect = () => {
    this.toggleSelect = !this.toggleSelect;
   };
    selectPhoneCode = (ccode) => {
    this.selectedCode = ccode;
    this.toggleSelect = false;
    this.updateprofile.MobilePhone = CommonConstants.STRING_EMPTY; // CLEAR MOBILE
  };
```

Comment: Check out the angular Material Autocomplete component: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: @matsch thank you for this. do you have sample for autocomplete code application? thank you

Comment: I have not tried this myself, but I am planning to use the Angular Material Version for my project. Check this StackBlitz for a working Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msvaxo?file=src/app/autocomplete-display-example.ts